# How to fadeout and remove elements created by ng-repeat

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

I have list of messages create using:

```
var messages = ["Foo Bar", "Lorem Ipsum", "Dolor Sit Amet"];
app.controller('fooControler', function($scope) {
    $scope.messages = [
        {"message": "Hello There"}
    ];
    function insert() {
        var random = Math.round(Math.random()*(messages.length-1));
        var message = messages[random];
        messages.splice(random, 1);
        $scope.$apply(function() {
            $scope.messages.push({message: message});
        });
        if (messages.length) {
            setTimeout(insert, 5000);
        }
    }
    setTimeout(insert, 5000);
});
```

and my ng-html look like this:

```
<html ng-app="app">

<body ng-controller="fooControler">
    <header>
        <div>You have {{messages.length}} messages</div>
        <ul ng-repeat="message in messages">
            <li>{{message.message}}</li>
        </ul>
    </header>
</body>
</html>
```

How can I FadeOut the messages and remove them? I know how to do that in jQuery but how can I do this using AngularJS way?

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Gepzn/)

Comment: May be this will be helpful: http://code.angularjs.org/1.1.4/docs/api/ng.directive:ngAnimate

Comment: when do you want to remove the item

Comment: @ArunPJohny in setTimeout after few seconds.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Start from AngularJS 1.1.4, the [ngAnimate](http://code.angularjs.org/1.1.4/docs/api/ng.directive%3angAnimate) directive is added to support the animation.

You can achieve it like this:

```
<ul ng-repeat="message in messages" ng-animate="'animate'">
    <li>{{message.message}}</li>
</ul>
```

And this is the css needed:

```
.animate-enter-setup, .animate-leave-setup {
    -webkit-transition: 1s linear all;
    /* Safari/Chrome */
    -moz-transition: 1s linear all;
    /* Firefox */
    -ms-transition: 1s linear all;
    /* IE10 */
    -o-transition: 1s linear all;
    /* Opera */
    transition: 1s linear all;
    /* Future Browsers */
}
.animate-enter-setup {
    opacity: 0;
}
.animate-enter-setup.animate-enter-start {
    /* The animation code itself */
    opacity: 1;
}
.animate-leave-setup {
    opacity: 1;
}
.animate-leave-setup.animate-leave-start {
    /* The animation code itself */
    opacity: 0;
}
```

<kbd>**[Working Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/BKw3D/1/)**</kbd>

Comment: Is it possilbe to animate on demand like on click or in setTimeout?

Comment: @jcubic I don't know what you want to achieve. Animation is automatically added if you use ngAnimate. Btw, you should use $timeout instead of setTimeout since $timeout deals with scope digest automatically.

Comment: Checked your demo again, and animation show before remove as I want, thanks.